# What is /dev/tty in UNIX?

Tags: unix

Both stdin and stdout file descriptors point to it. How does it work? Can some one point to a good resource for understanding UNIX terminals and system calls that interact with it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`dev/tty` is a file system object that represents the current console. Copying files into this "directory" from the command line prints out the content of these files to your console:

```
cp myfile.txt /dev/tty
```

is equivalent to

```
cat myfile.txt
```

These objects are there to let you use the familiar file APIs to interact with console. It is a clever way to unify console API with file API. You can use `fopen`, `fprintf`, etc. to interact with the console in the same way that you interact with regular files.

This example writes `"Hello, world\n"` to the terminal:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE *f = fopen("/dev/tty", "w");
    fprintf(f, "Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are pseudoterminals? How can I interact with them?

Comment: @Bruce Pseudo-terminals are abstractions along the lines of `/dev/tty` that represent, for example, other logical terminals that do not correspond to the physical terminal. You can see them at work by opening two xterm windows, typing `tty` in them to see their pseudo-terminal names, and then copying a file in one window into the other. For example, if you type `tty` and you get `/dev/ttys002` in one window and `/dev/ttys000` in the other, you can copy a file from one xterm into the `ttys...` of the other, and the content would display in the other window.

Comment: what's the application/use of unifying the two API and providing such a feature?

Comment: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1454/is-the-question-on-topic-herenot-meta

Comment: @hus787 UNIX provides lots of filter-like commands for working with files, and writing the output back to a file. This unification lets you buy an ability to write to a screen super-cheaply. The best thing is that the approach will work for the old programs and for the programs that have not been written yet in the same way.