# Running python script by " | bash " with sys.stdin.readline()

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am doing something need to use `curl xxx | bash` to run something.
I created a python script with `sys.stdin.readline()` to test like this:

```
[python3] test.py


import sys
def read_input():
    input = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
    print(input)
read_input()
```

It works directly run by `python3 test.py`

```
test
test
```

But if I use `echo 'python3 test.py' | bash`, it will not stop to let me input something.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pipe with `|`, you are redirecting the output from the first command into the input of the second. This means standard input of the second command doesn't connect to the terminal, and therefore cannot read keyboard input. The form `curl xxx | bash` therefore only functions for non-interactive scripts. This is in no way specific to Python.

You could in principle work around this by saving the input descriptor under another number, but it does get quite complex:

```
$ ( echo 'exec <&3 3<&- ; echo script starts ; read hello ; echo you entered $hello ; exit' | bash ) 3<&0
script starts
something
you entered something
```

Here I used `()` to create a subshell, in which stdin is duplicated on file descriptor 3 using `3<&0`, and the script generated in the pipeline both renames that back as stdin with `exec <&3 3<&-` and `exit`s to prevent further commands from being read from the restored stdin. This has side effects, such as descriptor 3 being open for the `echo` command.

Since the main reason to use `curl address | bash` in the first place is to keep the command simple, this is not what you're after. Besides, the pipe prevents you from handling if anything goes wrong during your download; your script could be interrupted anywhere. A traditional download then run isn't that much worse:

```
curl -O http://somewhere/somefile.py && python somefile.py
```

In comparison, this saves `somefile.py` to your filesystem. There are downsides to that, like requiring a writable filesystem and replacing that particular filename. On the upside, if anything goes wrong it stops there and doesn't run a corrupted script, due to `&&`.

One final possibility if the script you're downloading fits within the command line might be to put it there rather than in a pipe:

```
python -c "$(curl $url)"
```

This carries the same weaknesses to interrupted downloads, and additionally places the script contents in a command line which is generally public information (consider `ps ax` output). But if you're just downloading the script with curl, the information on how to get it likely was too. As this doesn't redirect stdin, it might be the answer to your immediate question.

In general, I recommend **not** to run any scripts straight off the internet without verification as this `curl something | bash` command line does. It's way too vulnerable to hijacking, as there's no verification involved for any step. It's better to use a package repository which checks signatures, such as apt.

Another method to get access to a terminal on Linux is via the device [`/dev/tty`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435308/what-is-dev-tty-in-unix). This method is used for instance [when `ssh` asks for a password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171835/how-does-ssh-prompt-for-a-password-when-all-input-and-output-is-redirected). It might also be possible to reopen stdout or stderr for input, as in `( exec < /dev/null ; read foo <&2 ; echo $foo )`.