# Trouble running a compiled FORTRAN program.. failing with error trying to open a file at line 61

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have no experience in Fortran having written code in C# and Aurelia.

I was interested in a program that designs turbine blades and would have liked to use it to explore a design process however its supplied as a program ready to compile and run.

Here is the Dropbox with the program. (there are 3 such programs this being the first in a series)

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8i0jyxzjb57q4j4/AADwCp9bufU-_uug9yHmvQYma/MEANGEN/meangen%20program?dl=0&preview=meangen-17.4.f&subfolder_nav_tracking=1

Instructions on the use of this are a couple of folders up..

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8i0jyxzjb57q4j4/AAAh1Jq_WkJfDSRet69Rxfo-a/MEANGEN/meangen-instructions.pdf?dl=0

I have installed minGW-W64 added to the path and then attempted to run the program. Where I think I should get a bunch of questions etc It runs and stops with an error. So I was able to compile it but it fails trying to open a file.

```
At line 61 of file mengen.f (unit = 5)
Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file '/dev/tty': No such file or directory

Error termination. Backtrace:

Could not print backtrace: libbacktrace could not find executable to open
#0  0xffffffff
#1  0xffffffff
#2  0xffffffff
#3  0xffffffff
#4  0xffffffff
#5  0xffffffff
#6  0xffffffff
#7  0xffffffff
#8  0xffffffff
#9  0xffffffff
#10  0xffffffff
#11  0xffffffff
```

I looked at the code and its trying to open a file called `/dev/tty` here is the line 60.

```
C
  OPEN(UNIT=10, FILE= 'meangen.out')
  OPEN(UNIT=5,  FILE= '/dev/tty')
C
```

Anybody out there who might know how to fix this and get it to work?

Comment: That's unix specific. Run it on Linux or something.

Comment: My usual policy is - if you have windows as your OS only use tool chains which are made for windows. All that mingw and cygwin stuff makes me cringe. Even if it costs you some bucks - I am sure you can find a fortran which works natively on windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435308/what-is-dev-tty-in-unix

Comment: @BitTickler The problem is not Fortran, the problem is the application (that happens to be written in Fortran).

Comment: Well then I guess he has to port it. ``/dev/tty`` is the terminal. So he would have to use something like ``GetStdHandle()`` on windows. And maybe read up on the new vt features that came with windows 10.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/276059 might give some ideas how to start.

Comment: Thanks for the comments... run it on Linix huh. I guess I can do that but I will have to install Linix.  So If I run this on Linix do you reckon I might have a better chance? Would you know that Linix can handle tty?

Comment: Please do NOT present the code as a Dropbox link or any other external link. The question must remain useful for others. And I will not click on any suspicious links myself. It is Linux, not Linix, and yes, any Linux should handle that. Or any other Unix, MacOS included. You can try installing Linux in your Windows using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10